# Multiple arguments in a copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I need to make a copy constructor that copies one value from the previous object, and creates a new value for the next. For example, in the first object x=1 and y=2, the second object copies the x value from the first one but assigns a different value for y (ex. x=1, y=3). I'm trying to add an argument in the copy constructor that will take the new value of y, but when I do this the values I get are (0, 32766). What's wrong with my code? I don't understand why the value of y is not changing properly.

```
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
public:
    int x, y;

    // constructor
    Point();
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}

    // copy constructor
    Point(Point &foo, int y) {
        this->x = foo.x;
        y = foo.y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Point p (0, 1);
    std::cout << "Original object (" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")\n";

    Point copy(p, 5);
    std::cout << "Copied object (" << copy.x << ", " << copy.y << ")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not really making a copy, though. So trying to abuse the copy constructor is a bad idea (generally). Just call your parameterized constructor and give it the appropriate information.

Comment: The shown class does not have a copy constructor. A copy-constructor, by definition, has exactly one parameter: the copied-from object. Any more parameters and it's not a copy constructor, any more. And the not-copy constructor this class has sets `y`, one of the parameters to the constructor, with the value of `foo.y`. There happens to be class member of the same name called `y`, true. But, when you have a class member and a constructor parameter with the same name, such as `y`, guess which `y` is `y`? VTC as a typo.

Comment: I guess `y = foo.y` should be `this->y = y`, and as already said, what you are writing maybe great, but by definition it is not a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining a copy constructor, just another constructor.

Best to write the whole thing like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

int main()
{
    Point p{0, 1};
    std::cout << "Original object (" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")\n";

    Point copy{p.x, 5};
    std::cout << "Copied object (" << copy.x << ", " << copy.y << ")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Having a constructor that takes half a Point and an int is just confusing. For larger structs you could have

```
Point with_y(int y_)
{
    return Point(x, y_);
}
```

but for a Point that seems pointless, excuse the pun.